# Re-render igGrid after initial canceling of rendering event

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I would ask for advice how to overcome following problem related to the usage of igGird:

- I'm using igGrid with Filtering and Selection widgets;
- After data-binding of the grid I'm cancelling the "dataRendering" event, because I expect a lot of data to be returned by the server and don't want to be displayed yet;
- On the same page that's holding the grid, there are some other controls that user can play with and based on their inputs I'm creating filtering criteria;
- When the filtering criteria is ready I'm applying filtering on the grid's data through "filter" method.
- Just when most of the date is cut-out, I want to show the remaining;
- I couldn't find render or rerender method in documentation;

How to make the gird to render its data again?

Thank, you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `dataBind` method again with a parameter `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Konstantin! Due to lack of time, I had to reconsider cancelling "dataRendering" event. Later today I will try what you suggested me and will edit this comment in order to thank you or to ask additional questions.

Comment: Try it out and let me know!

Comment: Absolutely right!
$(".selector").igGrid('dataBind', true);